# How to use custom widget with model/view/delegates in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwidgets

In the proprietary code base I'm currently working with, there is a custom list view (derived form `QListView`).

Currently it has an issue when lots of items (>10000) make the main thread freeze.
Every item in the view is a custom widget designed in QtDesigner.

To render every row, we use `setIndexWidget`, which is called on `QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted` signal. For every inserted row, from `first` to `last` custom widget is set for every index.

I tried to port this code to use `QStyledItemDelegate`, because disconnecting item widget from actual model seems to solve slow rendering.

Qt5 in that case can render items in view lazily, on demand. We will not need to create every widget for view before displaying the list.

I achieved initial results, using a class which is derived from `QStyledItemDelegate`. I create a list item widget in constructor and then override paint event like this.

```
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        auto baseWid = getBaseWidget(); // Get's list item widget pointer
        setSubEditorData(baseWid,index); // Set's it's state to display current item
        baseWid->resize(option.rect.size());
        QPixmap pixmap(option.rect.size());
        baseWid->render(&pixmap);
        painter->drawPixmap(option.rect, pixmap);
    }
```

This is sufficient for static content, but my widget has checkboxes and can be selected.

I don't really understand how to make it interactive, while preserving benefits delegates provide (rendering on demand and so on).

My question is how to make delegate handle user events? Like mouse clicks, selection changes.

Qt5 examples covering delegates are too simple, I don't understand how to draw with delegate a custom widget.

Comment: Why it inserts 10K widgets at once instead of fetching them on demand? I think you should fix rather the model instead of the delegate.

Comment: @vahancho legacy code

Comment: Can you override the original model and replace it in the view?

Comment: @vahancho yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

The best workaround I tried to use involves dynamic switching between the static rendered `QPixmap` and real widget when mouse moves or delegate receives event.

First I override `QAbstractItemDelegate::editorEvent`, so when delegate receives any event it switches to real widget for that `QModelIndex`.

Switching to real widget is done using `QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor`. After that call `QAbstractItemDelegate::createEditor` is automatically invoked to obtain widget.

```
bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) override
{
    auto view = qobject_cast<NyView*>(parent());
    view->openPersistentEditor(index);
    return Base::editorEvent(event, model, option, index);
}
```

In my view I also enabled every described way to open editor.

```
this->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::EditTrigger::AllEditTriggers);
this->setMouseTracking(true);
connect(this, &MyView::entered, this, &MyView::openPersistentEditor);
```

`QAbstractItemView::entered` signal is emitted when mouse is hovered on widget.

At user perspective nothing changes, before they can interact with list item it's already dynamically replaces with real widget.

Some garbage collection strategy seems to be necessary too, because if user hovers over many widgets they remain in memory even if they didn't interact with it for long time. For deleted rows editors are automatically destroyed, but this may be insufficient.

Open source Qt5 based software (Telegram Desktop) renders large list without using widgets. They render list manually overriding `QWidget::paint` method and implementing virtualization (drawing only what is seen on screen).

Comment: I was actually going to recommend a similar solution to this one. Creating custom widgets when populating your container widget can be really expensive. I see you have connected `MyView::entered()` to `MyView::openPersistenEditor()`, but I think you should also call `MyView::closePersistentEditor()` in order to delete the widget. Otherwise you might have a memory leak. That's because `createEditor()` is creating the widget on the heap, and either `QWidget::close()` or `QWidget::deleteLater()` must be called on it in order to free the memory.